# Converse of a result related to normal matrices

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

If $A_i$ are commuting normal matrices, then

$$\displaystyle\sup_{\|y\|=1}\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n|\langle A_iy,y\rangle|^2\bigg)=\displaystyle\sup_{\|y\|=1}\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\|A_iy\|^2\bigg)\;.$$

> Is the converse of this result true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no, just take $A_1$ and $A_2$ a pair of unitary operators with one common eigenvector $x_0$; the right-hand side of the equation equals $2$ for all $x$ and the left-hand side reaches this maximum of $2$ for $x=x_0$, but there is no reason why $A_1$ and $A_2$ should commute.

---

example:
$$A_1=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \cos \phi_1 & \sin \phi_1 \\
 0 & -\sin \phi_1 & \cos \phi_1 \\
\end{array}\right),\;\;A_2=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \cos \phi_2 & \sin \phi_2 \\
 0 & \sin \phi_2 & -\cos \phi_2 \\
\end{array}\right)$$
single common eigenvector is $(1,0,0)$ and they do not commute:
$$A_1 A_2 - A_2 A_1=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 \sin \phi_1 \sin \phi_2 & -2 \cos \phi_2 \sin \phi_1 \\
 0 & -2 \cos \phi_2 \sin \phi_1 & -2 \sin \phi_1\sin \phi_2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: I've added a simple $3\times 3$ example (don't think there is $2\times 2$ example)

Comment: you only need $\sin\phi_1\neq 0$, but $\phi_2$ is not restricted.